# What is a proper term to describe a server running source control, bug tracking and CI tools?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a 'term' that describes holistically the set of various software development tools/services that most developers use on a day to day basis. While each tool by itself has a specific purpose and can be described, is there a plural term when they are grouped together and running as a holistic service.

If a person said a server was a production test box, I'd expect it to be running the application that company are writing. If a person said box A is the office ware server, I'd know to expect email/communication related services.

Comment: "Polymorphic" service? It responds differently to the same requests? Perhaps multi-use would be a better adjective.

Comment: Yeah, the "polymorphic" thing puzzles me. Perhaps what you mean is "holistic"?

Comment: We put SVN, bugtracker (Redmine) etc. all on one machine. We call it - DevCentral. Some people also call it forge!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that there is a mismatch between the question heading, and the actual question.

The heading refers to the actual machine that is running theses tools. I believe the common term for this is a 'Build Server'

But the actual question reads more like, what is the common name for the tools themselves, as a whole. And I believe here the most common term is a 'Tool Chain'

Answer (score 4):

I've been using the term "build environment" or "build server" which covers our:

- SVN Server
- Issue tracking
- CCNet
- Test case management
- Development wiki
- etc

It was the best term we could come up with at the time.

Answer (score 4):

- **SCM server** (*SCM* stands for Software Configuration Management)
- **ALM server** (*ALM* stands for Application Lifecycle Management). Actually, this one would be more appropriate for your stack of tools.

Comment: +1 for ALM, this was the first thing that came to my mind

Comment: If it wasn't here that's what I was going to say. All of that would be grouped under the umbrella of ALM.

Answer (score 1):

Build server is probably as good a name as any, even though you'd be doing more than just running your build on it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use "Developer Toolchain". The term originally meant text editor + compiler + linker, but I think bug tracking, version control and others are equally essential to software development these days, so they can be included in the definition.